# Creating 5 random elements with ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

My requirements:

- They need to be created on random positions.
- You should be able to click and move them.
- Once they touch each other, you're not able to move them anymore.
- They change colors once they touch.

This is my code now,but it keeps creating balls an  infinite amount of them

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//Criação das variavéis
var bolas:Array = new Array();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startdd);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdd);

function startdd(e:MouseEvent)
{
e.target.startDrag();
}

function stopdd(e:MouseEvent)
{
    e.target.stopDrag();
    }


    for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    var ball:bolamc = new bolamc();
    ball.x = Math.random() * (stage.stageWidth - ball.width);
    ball.y = Math.random() * (stage.stageHeight - ball.height);
    bolas.push(ball);
    stage.addChild(ball);
    }
```

ps: my friend is using the same code and its working properly (makes 5 balls and he's able to move them around)

Comment: @Zhafur yes he did fix and now even I would feel alright to try help him.     @ Eksu No one was being rude. Your original question came across as "I want xyz, give me now" rather "I have tried to do..." and most advisors would not touch it like that. Chillax, we were actually helping you. Peace

Comment: PS: In reply to your question try a colour transform on the movieclips: [useful tutorials](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=as3+movieclip+color+transform). Also consider using different names for `balls` the array and `balls` the movieClip as that could cause problems further on

Comment: Agreed with @VC.One, if some sees such post, they flag it, down vote it and not even answering. (meant for the first form of the question) :)

Comment: I have a new problem now,my code keeps making balls,nonstop.I updated again.Sorry the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to write most of the code yourself, but I can give you some guidance.

To create an element in a random spot on the screen, you can use [Math.random()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#random%28%29). Example:

```
var newElement:Element = new Element();
newElement.x = Math.random()*STAGE_WIDTH_GOES_HERE;
newElement.y = Math.random()*STAGE_HEIGHT_GOES_HERE;
addChild(newElement);
```

For clicking and dragging, [here's a nice tutorial on Kirupa](http://www.kirupa.com/flash/easy_drag_drop_flash_as3.htm). You might need to adjust it to make it work with multiple objects.

For hit collision, you can loop through your elements and use [hitTestObject()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29) to determine if their bounding boxes are touching each other. If you need greater precision, you can try a pixel perfect collision class like [this](http://www.freeactionscript.com/2011/08/as3-pixel-perfect-collision-detection/).

For changing the color of an object, you can use [Color Transform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html), which has a tutorial on [RepublicOfCode](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3colortransform/). Here's some basic example code from that page:

```
var myColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
myColorTransform.color = 0xFFFFFF;
myTargetObject.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;
```

Comment: @Eksu, if you found an answer constructive, then you can upvote it and/or accept it as an answer to your question. This also helps the community, increasing people's reputation and helps those who are having the same problem, searching through the net and see this question with an accepted answer. Some people may not bother reading answers which are not accepted.